# Can't get around to how to pass a function as a parameter

Tags: c, pthreads, function-pointers

I'm trying to pass this function: `void* checkMatrix();` as an argument to this function: `void createThreads(void*(*f));`.

I've read a post here so my decleration above is a result of this.

I'm calling the function like this: `createThreads(checkMatrix);` but it gives me a warning that type is incompatible [void** and void*()]. I can get around with a fast cast but it won't fix the problem.

Finally I write the function like this (simple initialization):

```
void createThreads(void* (*f)) {
    pthread_t* a;
    int i;

    a = (pthread_t*) malloc(*arr.l * sizeof(pthread_t));
    if (a == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < *arr.l; i++) {
        if (pthread_create((a + i), NULL, (void*) &f, NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR IN THREAD CREATION!\n");
            exit(2);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < *arr.l; i++)
        pthread_join(*(a + i), NULL);
}
```

In conclusion, the problem is that it stops, with memory problem, but the cause is the creation of the threads and espacially in the 3rd argument that I specify the function that the thread will work on. I think I'm doing something wrong with the calling. I can't find the answer and can't get around it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Use `void createThreads(void* (*f)(void *)) ` and just use `f` in `pthread_create`. (`f` is already a pointer, so no address-of needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void* (*f)` is just `void **f` with a set of redundant parentheses. You probably wanted to use this for the parameter type:

```
void* (*f)()
```

However, that is *not* what `pthread_create` expects. The thread's main function is supposed to return `void*` *and take a `void*` parameter*. So what you really want is probably this:

```
void createThreads(void* (*f)(void*)) {
  /* ... as before ... */
          if (pthread_create((a + i), NULL, f, NULL)) {
  /* ... as before ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To begin with `void* checkMatrix();` is obsolete style and shouldn't be used. Second, pthread callback functions take `void*` as parameter. So use `void* checkMatrix(void*);` instead.

To pass it to a function, simply do

```
void createThreads (void* (*f)(void*))
```

Recommended practice when using function pointers is otherwise to use typedefs, to increase readability. For example you could cook up something like

```
typedef void* pthread_callback (void*);

void createThreads (pthread_callback* f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the function signature to `void createThreads(void* (*f)(void *))`
and change the pthread_create function call to`pthread_create((a + i), NULL, f, NULL)`